# Thymealf layout : javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf template that looks like:

```
<body>

<div id="layout">
    <!-- Menu toggle -->
    <a href="#menu" id="menuLink" class="menu-link">
        <!-- Hamburger icon -->
        <span></span>
    </a>

    <!-- Menu -->
     <div th:replace="laberint/common/menu :: [//div[@id='menu']]"></div>
```

and the menu looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <!-- Menu -->
    <div id="menu" oncontextmenu='return false' ondragstart='return false' onmousedown='return false'>
     ......

     <script th:inline="javascript">
     alert ('lalala');
     </script>



    </html>
```

But I don't see the alert when I load the page

Comment: Are there any errors in the js console? Did you check the final source of the page to see if the menu is actually there? Are you sure that this framework supports scripts? (because it could be XSS safe and won't allow arbitrary execution of js code)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after put it inside a div

```
 <script th:inline="javascript">
     alert ('lalala');
     </script>
 </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html) suggests using a popup div instead of a JavaScript alert:

> This is an example of a reusable alert fragment using layout:fragment
>   (task/alert.html):
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <body>
>     <th:block layout:fragment="alert-content">
>         <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula...</p>
>         <p>
>             <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Take this action</button>
>             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Or do this</button>
>         </p>
>     </th:block>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> The calling of the above fragment may look as follows
>   (task/list.html):
>
> ```
> <div layout:insert="~{task/alert :: alert}" th:with="type='info', header='Info'" th:remove="tag">
>     <!--/* Implements alert content fragment with simple content */-->
>     <th:block layout:fragment="alert-content">
>         <p><em>This is a simple list of tasks!</em></p>
>     </th:block>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Or:

```
<div layout:insert="~{task/alert :: alert}" th:with="type='danger', header='Oh snap! You got an error!'" th:remove="tag">
    <!--/* Implements alert content fragment with full-blown HTML content */-->
    <th:block layout:fragment="alert-content">
       <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula...</p>
        <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
            Take this action</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            Or do this</button>
        </p>
    </th:block>
</div>
```

> In this case, the entire alert-content of task/alert
>   (/WEB-INF/views/task/alert.html) template will be replaced by custom
>   HTML above.

So, the example in the OP might look like this:

```
<div layout:insert="~{task/alert :: alert}" th:with="type='info', header='lalala'" th:remove="tag">
        <th:block layout:fragment="alert-content">
            <p>La la la</p>
        </th:block>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
```

replace your script tag with the above code and works fine

Comment: I did it, but I don't see it when I see the source code of the template :-(